# Thread is not aborted and waits on dispatcher invoke?

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke, dispatcher, thread-abort

(WPF c# application) . I have mainwindow UI  thread where I use a dispatcher invoke in many places of the code. From main thread I start another thread. I try to abort the thread immediately  by clicking a cancel button. On cancel button click I use Thread.abort() to terminate the thread. But thread does not abort. I observed that dispatcher invoke is waiting and UI is not responding.
I want to run the thread synchronously and not use begininvoke..?

button cancel event  is in class A ,we are calling thread abort.

Threadx.abort();

when thread abort is called we are calling custom message box  from the thread via delegate

custom message box calling looks like this and is in class A

```
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {

                    QMessageBox = new QatMessageBox(this);
                    result = QMessageBox.Show(messageBoxTest, messageBoxCaption, messageBoxButton, messageBoxImage);


            }));
```

custom message box looks like this and is in a separate class

```
       public QatMessageBox(Window owner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Owner = owner;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Comment: and where is the code, please share some code to identified the error

Comment: I guess that your Background Thread is Waiting at Disptacher Invoke for the UI Thread which on the other hand is waiting for Thread.Abort. which causes a deadlock. But as already mentioned - show us some code to identify the problem.

Comment: "I use Thread.abort() to terminate the thread" - don't. Please add your code, so we can suggest improvements.

Comment: As mentioned by Console.. I'm facing a deadlock condition. code waits at this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>{somecode})); also waits at Thread.abort()..Which I observed in parallel stacks MS vs 17.

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke() is dangerous and likely to cause deadlock.  You need to use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window to diagnose it, good odds that you see the main thread doing something it should not be doing, like waiting for the thread to complete.  It is rarely actually necessary, and is not here, BeginInvoke() is a lot less risky.  You also can't swing a dead cat and not hit somebody that tells you to never use Thread.Abort()

Comment: on threads view i get as below                                                                     Not Flagged  16372 27 Worker Thread <No Name> WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.DispatcherOperationEvent.WaitOne Normal